# Print or die: how to check if a GPFS network mounted file is available

Tags: perl, networking, filesystems, system

I have a Perl script that writes to a file located on a GPFS network mounted storage point. There is a standard check `open FILE or die $!`.

The file system went down, but the script did not quit; it kept trying to write. The Perl script finished once the file system came back up. How can I check whether the file system can be written to, and `die` if it cannot?

The reason I ask this is because the last line of my Perl script removes the file's `.tmp` extension. This statement should never have been reached because at one point the script's output wasn't going anywhere. GPFS was down on the write point, but the read point was still up.

Comment: "print"? Perhaps you mean "write"?

Comment: @MarcB: Calling `print` to a file handle is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Borodin: I'm thinking bigger picture. perl might be using "print" as the function call's name, but it's still "writing" to the file system.

Comment: @MarcB: That's what I understood from your comment, but it doesn't mean the question is wrongly phrased.

Comment: @user3574820: You don't have to do what everybody tells you. Trying to do so can lead you to being pulled in several directions at once. Your original text was fine, and IMO MarcB is being excessively picky.

Answer (score 5):

`print` has a return code. Most people don't bother to check it. But it does have one.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html

> print
>   Prints a string or a list of strings. Returns true if successful.

So yes, you can do 'print or die'. But you do need to make sure you bracket it correctly, so the 'or' associates with the right expression.

```
print 0 || warn "1 failed";
print 0 or warn "2 failed";
```

This will give two different results, because the former 'tests' the zero. where the latter tests the `print`. If you bracket the print, then this doesn't matter, which might be desirable for the sake of clarity.

So if testing - you can do:

```
open ( my $fh, "<", "bad_open" ); #opens read only, so prints will fail. 

print {$fh} 0,1,2 || warn "1 failed";
print {$fh} 1,2,3  or warn "2 failed";
```

(I was going to suggest [`autodie`](http://search.cpan.org/~nthykier/autodie-2.26/lib/autodie.pm#print) but sadly it doesn't get applied to `print`. )

Alternatively, looking at the manpage for GPFS:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKCN_3.5.0/com.ibm.cluster.gpfs.v3r5.gpfs100.doc/bl1adm_gsmo.htm

Can I suggest checking your mount options? Is your GPFS NFS mounted on your client?

Looking at it, GPFS doesn't support `soft` mounting like NFS. By design, a `soft` mount will fail a write on a transient error, where `hard` mounts will block whilst the mount is offline.

`hard` is the default, because then you avoid data corruption - anything writing will block until the mount recovers. It looks like it's `hanging` which can seen undesirably, but bear in mind that it greatly improves data integrity.

I don't know if there's an easy test for a 'stalled' hard mount from within a script. If you're network mounting your GPFS over NFS, you may find you can simply mount it as `soft` instead (perhaps using a separate mountpoint and mounting twice if that'll affect others).

Comment: This was my first thought, but the OP says *"Once the file system went back up, the perl script finished"*. So it sounds like the `print` statement was suspended waiting for the file system to return. If it completed and returned a bad status then the program would have completed immediately.

Comment: I had interpreted that differently, as the filesystem had gone offline, failed the prints, but been back online in time to complete. But perhaps it's a mount-options sort of question instead.

Comment: Sobrique has it right, the scripts take many hours to run, and GPFS went down form only a few hours.