# Why does perl's autodie feature not include "print"? (And is there a workaround?)

Tags: perl

Having had a bit of a look for another question ( [Print or die: how to check if a GPFS network mounted file is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487318/print-or-die-how-to-check-if-a-gpfs-network-mounted-file-is-available/28488504#28488504) ) `autodie` is quite a useful pragma, because it makes a variety of calls that should *probably* be fatal, actually fatal.

Things like `open` - it's quite common to write `open or die`.

But the problem with autodie is:

> print
>
> The autodie pragma **does not check calls to print.**

You can't force it to either:

```
Cannot make the non-overridable builtin print fatal
```

So short of writing my own 'print_or_die' sub, is there a way to replicate something similar to the `autodie` pragma, that also traps `print` return codes?

(For a scenario where this might be relevant - see the above link. NFS soft mounts error on writes, they don't block)

Comment: I would only add to the question, can `close()` succeed if some of the `print()` failed before that.

Comment: The problem is that the print operator has a syntax that subs can't replicate. It is possible, but much harder.

Comment: I think close can succeed where print failed - aside from the example I linked, I think 'disk full' would allow you to open/close a zero length file, but not successfully print to it. Or maybe just making an error, and opening a file for reading rather than writing.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about your disk example

Comment: testing with `use autodie; open my $fh, ">", "/dev/full"; select $h; $|=1; print "x" or warn "print failed with $! (".($!+0).")"; close $fh`, both the print and close fail (and with buffering, just the close fails)

Comment: err, that should have been `select $fh`

Answer (score -4):

Seems to me, you have answer by yourself:

> because it [autodie] makes a variety of calls that should probably be
>   fatal, actually fatal.

`print` mostly should not be fatal, as far I understand, so your offered workaround `print_or_die` seems solution too.

Comment: My problem is - if I want file IO to 'bomb out' - I want that applying to everything - open, print, close. Print _can_ fail despite open/close working. (Disk full, broken mount, etc.). You _should_ therefore be testing print, if you're doing this, to avoid file corruption. (or at least, you can tell if your successfully 'wrote' your output).